# In Word 2013 is it possible to make the first few pages numbers Roman Numerals and the rest normal digits?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, microsoft-word-2013, page-numbers

For example I want the first 3 pages to have the footer i, ii, iii and after that I want 4, 5, 6 etc. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to first create a section break then add the footers.

Here is the tutorial:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-different-page-numbers-or-number-formats-to-different-sections-HA102809694.aspx

Comment: I think you mean footers, not foot notes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When you add a [Section Break](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-section-breaks-HA102840166.aspx), it will make Word treat the headers and footers differently before and after the section break. You can then customize the headers and footers appropriately.